# Mathplotlib draw delta on curve + bars under function

Tags: python, function, plot, curve

I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gamma = 0.5

p = np.linspace(1/253, 253/253, 253)
y = np.power(p, gamma)

plt.plot(p, y)
plt.xlabel('p')
plt.ylabel('\u03C6(p)')
plt.title(' ')
plt.show()
```

which gives me this figure: https://ibb.co/M7B1PD1

And I have this code:

```
p = np.linspace(1/253, 253/253, 253)

b = 0.5
phi_p = np.power((b * p), (b-1))

plt.plot(p, phi_p)
plt.xlabel('p')
plt.ylabel('\u03A6(p)')
plt.title(' ')
plt.show()
```

which gives me this figure: https://ibb.co/5xRR1k6

Now I want this for the first figure:https://ibb.co/nzdpfNc
and this for the second one: https://ibb.co/yYCp7HD

So in the first picture the delta of the curve should be shown and in the second picture a bar for each i in (0,253) should be drawn under the curve.

Is there I way to do this with mathplotlib? I had the idea to draw a histogram under the curve but I don't solve this well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the delta under the curve, just pair up your data points one at a time and then plot it. For instance

```
x_data=[1,4,6]
y_data=[2,3,7]
delta_to_plot_x=[1,4,4,6,6]
delta_to_plot_y=[2,2,3,3,7]
```

and this function should work at generating the right values.

```
def make_delta_for_plot(x,y):
    new_x=[val for val in x for _ in (0, 1)]
    new_y=[val for val in y for _ in (0, 1)]
    new_x.pop(0)
    new_y.pop(-1)
    return new_x,new_y
```

For the second plot, [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) can plot distributions with histograms at the same time (and it uses matplotlib so it will work fine with the rest of your code). There are plenty of examples in the link

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, the Idea with the histogram was wrong. I just want to plot a bar under the curve for each in (1/253,253/253).

Comment: But do the bars correspond to the values of the curve? Then it really is just a histogram, as long as you specify the bins correctly

Comment: I solved it. Look in the start post for the solution.

Thank you for your work!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you came up with a solution, but I still recommend that you look into seaborn. It has really nice visualizetions and its a good thing to learn

Comment: I will do so! In the moment I got a tunneld view on the packages I know so far. Thats because I just started to code. But seaborn is one of the packages I have to go into.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the secound figure this way:

```
b = 0.5

p = np.array(np.arange(1/253, 253/253, 1/253))
phi_p = np.power((b * p), (b-1))

x = np.array(np.arange(1/253,253/253,1/253))

liste = []
for i in phi_p:
    liste.append(i)
y = liste

plt.plot(p, phi_p, color='orange')
plt.bar(x0, liste, width=(1/253), edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('p')
plt.ylabel('\u03A6(p)')
plt.title(' ')
plt.show()
```